# Fetch everything or GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, concatenation

First of all, here's the query I will talk about :

```
SELECT route_id, direction_id
FROM stop_times
LEFT JOIN trips USING (trip_id)
WHERE stop_id= 1002
GROUP BY CONCAT(route_id, direction_id)
```

Example of the expected results :

```
route_id    |   direction_id
-----------------------------
106         |   0
106         |   1
13          |   0
13          |   1
21          |   0
4           |   0
4           |   1
6           |   0
```

So, running this query will take an averge of 0.088 second. This is ok... But if I remove the GROUP BY it take 0.0026 second.

Now my question is :

Will it be better to do the GROUP BY and handle everything in MySQL or fetch everything and handle it in an array in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY CONCAT(route_id, direction_id)` rather than `GROUP BY route_id, direction_id`? Or simply `SELECT DISTINCT route_id, direction_id` and drop the `GROUP BY` clause? (I'm also a bit confused by the `LEFT JOIN` when none of your expected results include `NULL`s, and I wonder if your join might be better converted to a subquery under `IN` or `EXISTS`; but without the table definitions, it's hard to tell.)

Comment: @ruakh +1 Not only is your correction going to be more efficient, it will avoid producing incorrect results. Imagine pairs of rows with `route_id` and `direction_id` of `12,1` and `1,21`. These would be erroneously grouped together when using `CONCAT`.

Comment: @ruakh Good question. I don't have an answer but yes you are right... did the test without and it take the same amount of time.

Comment: Please show your database structure for the tables/columns used in the query, including indexes.

Comment: The output of `EXPLAIN SELECT <your query>` also would help.

Comment: @MarcusAdams http://www.davidbelanger.net/s1.jpg http://www.davidbelanger.net/s2.jpg

Comment: The problem from the explain I see is it take a lot of time to put in tempory table the data.

Comment: I think I will need to use heavy cache with this query

Comment: Used cache file. Now it take 0.0001 second to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(route_id, direction_id)
```

by this:

```
GROUP BY route_id, direction_id
```

You will have the same results in much less time.

Comment: Depending on the data, you may not have the same results. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Things like `GROUP BY` are what databases are designed for. A difference of less than a hundredth of a second shouldn't be anything to be concerned about. No need to start optimizing until you actually have real performance problems.

Comment: The query in this case is too slow, because removing the `GROUP BY` makes it about 30 times faster. Besides, a query that takes almost a 10th of a second is probably (hopefully) one of the slowest elements when constructing a page. I suspect that the indexes can be improved.

Comment: @Arjan My page jump from 0.0026 to 0.1062 with this query and she's almost at the end.

Comment: @DavidBélanger That's what I mean... Your request doesn't need to take 0.1 seconds when it also could take 0.05 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Because the query is fast without the `GROUP BY` and slow when that is added, it seems to me that the indexes are not used for the grouping. In fact, it seems that there is no index that covers `route_id, direction_id` in `trips`. The only index in `trips` starts with `trip_id` and can not be used for this `GROUP BY`.

I would suggest to add an index on `route_id, direction_id` in `trips`. Note that the columns should be in the same order that's used in the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: I think it should be able to use the primary index on trips for the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index on the column `stop_times.stop_id`.

You should also consider getting rid of the CONCAT on the GROUP BY clause. I'm guessing that you're doing that in error.

I'm also wondering about the use of GROUP BY here. If you're using it to remove duplicates then you should be using DISTINCT. If you're using it to order the results, then use ORDER BY.

If you're still having problems, then please provide the result of EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT concat_route_direction
FROM
(SELECT CONCAT(route_id, direction_id) AS concat_route_direction
FROM stop_times
LEFT JOIN trips USING (trip_id)
WHERE stop_id= 1002) AS concat_route_direction
GROUP_BY concat_route_direction
```

I haven't tested it, let me know if it's not working what kind of error do you have

Comment: 0.0806 sec. Your query doesn't work because of `GROUP_BY` must be `GROUP BY` Just a typo mistake but I solved the problem using a cache (in PHP).